# Reverse the content order of several columns (ideally in tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse

Assuming the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c(1, 2, 6), c = c(4, 6, NA), d = c(6, NA, NA))

  a b  c  d
1 1 1  4  6
2 2 2  6 NA
3 3 6 NA NA
```

And what I want is:

```
  a b  c  d
1 1 6  4  1
2 2 6  2 NA
3 3 6 NA NA
```

I thought about some combination of `across` and `rev`, but my current attempts don't work.

Comment: Do you want to reverse the non-NA row values across b:d?

Comment: NA's should be kept at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
pivot_longer(df, -a) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(value=rev(value), .by=a) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Output:

```
      a     b     c     d
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     6     4     1
2     2     6     2    NA
3     3     6    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution:

```r
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) c(rev(x[complete.cases(x)]), x[is.na(x)])))

  a b  c  d
1 1 6  4  1
2 2 6  2 NA
3 3 6 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

First define a vector of target columns, then `paste` the non-`NA` values together into the same column row-wise. Then `separate` that column to a wide format.

```r
library(tidyverse)

target_cols <- c("b", "c", "d")

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(concat = paste0(rev(na.omit(c_across(all_of(target_cols)))), collapse = ","), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(cols = concat, names = target_cols, delim = ",", too_few ="align_start")

# A tibble: 3 × 4
      a b     c     d    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 6     4     1    
2     2 6     2     NA   
3     3 6     NA    NA
```